# How to solve $X_{xx}=(1+\delta{(x)})X$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I am trying to find the vibration modes of a string that has a uniform mass density, plus some point mass somewhere attached to it, modelled by an additional Dirac delta function in the mass density. The wave equation is of the form

$u_{xx}=(1+\delta{(x)})u_{tt}$,

where $u$ is the deformation, and $(1+\delta{(x)})$ the mass density. After separation of variables we find

$X_{xx}=(1+\delta{(x)})X$,

where $X$ is the spatial part of the solution. Is there any analytical solution for $X$?

Comment: Do you know how to solve $y''-y=\delta$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to solve the differential equation $y''(x) = (1+\delta(x)) y(x),$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta "function".

Since $f(x)\delta(x) = f(0)\delta(x)$ for every $f$ continuous at $x=0,$ the equation reduces to $y''(x) = y(x) + y(0)\delta(x),$ i.e. $y''(x)-y(x)=y(0)\delta(x).$ A solution to this is continuous, satisfies $y''-y=0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and on $(0,\infty),$ and its derivative makes a jump at $x=0$ which is equal to $y(0).$

Let $y(x)=Ae^{x} + Be^{-x}$ be the solution on $(-\infty, 0)$ and $y(x)=Ce^{x} + De^{-x}$ be the solution on $(0, \infty).$ Then, for continuity we shall have $A+B=C+D=:E,$ and to get $y''-y=y(0)\delta$ we shall have $(C-D)-(A-B)=y(0)=E.$

Now you only have to find all $A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A+B=C+D=(C-D)-(A-B).$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Just one thing, how do you find that the derivative makes a jump at 0?

Comment: And also that the solution continuous?

Comment: Somewhat simplified: If $y$ were discontinuous then $y'$ would have $\delta$-terms and $y''$ would have $\delta'$-terms. Similarly, $y'$ needs to have a step discontinuity to make $y''$ have a $\delta$-term, the $\delta$-term on the right hand side.

Comment: Oh right I see. Is it a general fact that in a differential equation of order n implying a delta function, the discontinuity happens in the n-1 th derivative?

Comment: At least when we have a linear differential equation with constant coefficients, it is.